# How do I redefine OAuth scope with service-configuration Meteor package?

Tags: meteor, google-api

I added the `service-configuration` package to my Meteor app and I'm trying to redefine auth scope for Google, particularly make the app request access to calendar. The default setup would be

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.update({}, {
  service: 'google',
  clientId: CLIENT_ID,
  secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
  loginStyle: 'redirect'
}, {
  upsert: true
});
```

So what I was trying to do was to add extra property to the options object:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.update({}, {
  service: 'google',
  clientId: CLIENT_ID,
  secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
  loginStyle: 'redirect',
  requestPermissions: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
  ]
}, {
  upsert: true
});
```

It didn't work. Docs are sparse. Can anybody have a little direction so I could access user's calendar data via Google APIs in a Meteor app?

I don't use Google's official Node package and not intended to do. I believe there's an easier way to access their APIs via transparent HTTP requests right from the app.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the two packages involved ([google](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/google), and [accounts-google](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-google/google.js)) it seems that you are putting the options in the wrong place. They are not read from the service configuration in the db but directly from the first argument to the `loginWithGoogle` function call.

That said, the following should work (with no change to the service configuration in the db):

```js
Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
    loginStyle: 'redirect',
    requestPermissions: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
    ]
}, function() { console.log("login successful); });
```

UPDATE:

If you are using the `loginButtons` template then it is even easier, as described in the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_ui_config):

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
    google: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: And what if I'm using the imported `{{> loginButtons}}` template?

Comment: This is what official doc tells but it doesn't work in my app, for some reason. I'll update my question as soon as I have more details to share.